# Number of Parameter Passed to Function?

Tags: c#

I want to know how many parameters can be passed to function, I mean what is good programming practice, regarding passing the parameters to function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fewer the better, but only if it still makes sense. I've never heard of a standard number of params to be passed, but I have heard of ways to keep them down better.

For example, don't do this:

```
public void DoSomething(string name, int age, int weight, ...) { }
```

but rather:

```
public void DoSomething(Person person) { }
```

but hopefully that goes without saying. But also, I would recommend not creating a weird class just to trim down the parameter count.

Comment: I would. I find that when I need that many parameters I tend to need them in multiple places or I need to constantly add more. This is why we have stuff like the EventArgs pattern in .NET.

Comment: Joel: good point in your answer, but I have already read in some article that if number of parameters are more then 5 then use structure. I like that statement that if you have more then 5 parameter then define struct and use that struct to pass parameters.

Comment: Hi All, I was working on a piece of code with my colleague. He was passing 15 parameters to a method. I insisted on creating a class called 'SearchCriteria' and populate the properties. My colleague argues that 15 parameters is easy as Visual studio gives the intellisense for the method. Not sure how to convince him. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

[Code Complete](http://www.cc2e.com/) suggests a maximum of 7. This is because of [The Magical Number Seven, Plus or Minus Two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magical_Number_Seven,_Plus_or_Minus_Two):

> ...the number of objects an average human can hold in working memory is 7 ± 2; this is frequently referred to as Miller's Law.

Here's an excerpt from Code Complete 2nd Edition:

> **Limit the number of a routine’s parameters to about seven**
>
> Seven is a magic number for people’s comprehension. Psychological research has found that people generally cannot keep track of more than about seven chunks of information at once (Miller 1956). This discovery has been applied to an enormous number of disciplines, and it seems safe to conjecture that most people can’t keep track of more than about seven routine parameters at once.

Comment: If the number is 7 ± 2, shouldn't we take the low end and say a maximum of 5?

Comment: @Jonathan See my edits. It's actually 7.

Comment: This is so true. I was once in a class while in the Air Force where the instructor put this sequence on the board, asked us to memorize it then repeat it back: C130KC10C140L1011C5. Not everyone in the Air Force actually sees airplanes but I happened to be writing a program dealing with cargo aircraft so I saw something much easier to remember: C130, KC10, C140, L1011, C5

Answer (score 4):

IMHO 5 at MAX.

6 is too much for me and 7 **overwhelming**!

Comment: So you comply to Millers law then, as Anton suggests :)

Comment: Yup Dude! The part of Millers law I don't like is "7+2" its too big a number...!

Answer (score 2):

According to Clean Code - maximum 3

Comment: Good luck creating a `Rectangle` constructor.

Comment: You can create a class and then pass and object to function

Answer (score 1):

If you have many things you would like to pass to a function you may want to look at some other means of transferring that data as opposed to simple parameter passing. For example in certain cases it may be better to generate an XML file and then pass values related to getting data around that XML file. If you are running a web app it may be simply passing data through sessions or post rather than get or function calls that will simplify your life.

Also you may want to store some of that information as member variables.

I would recommend no more than 4. You don't want your lines to get much longer than 30 characters long unless you are generating some massive string, but even then it becomes really unreadable and gross (although necessary especially for javascript).

Answer (score 1):

It's good programming practice to write programs so that they are easy to read. Personally I try not to write functions which have more parameters than can be displayed on one line on the screen. Usually that is no more than five or six parameters at most.

Answer (score 0):

some ARM compilers pass three or less parameters using registers and any more than three are stacked. The stacked type call is slower than the call using registers so in this case you should use three or less parameters, for speed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many parameters you are going to pass to a function use param for sending variable arguments to a method.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the architecture, more than 1-3 will cause passing on the stack. This is slower than passing via registers. From a performance standpoint, it is best to pass either a pointer to a wrapper class or a pointer to a struct. This ensures that only one value is passed in and saves some writes/reads to memory.